# Unity 3D Pool Simulation on the mobile devices

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, game-engine, rpc, game-physics

I am making pool game using unity3d game engine.
I have problem that when this game is run on two devices, the simulation on one device is not exactly as on the other device.
It(balls) gives noticeable jiterring on another device.
Any suggestion will help me.

Thank you

Comment: In NetworkView component-> State Synchronization what option you choose? If every component which have NetworkView Reliable Delta Compressed and there are many of them it may cause jittering problem. And also please notice that network speed is so important.

Comment: In my opinion, networking is not a issue. physics calculation on different devices causes the problem. if device 2 has strong processor rather than device 1, device 2 calculate the distance faster than device 1 and after syncing the ball re positioned according to the device 1 which causes the jitterring effect.

Comment: how can I solve this issue, any idea??

Comment: Are you using the built-in physics engine?